# Error during Jupyter installation

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I am trying to install Jupyter through pip, but I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\suyash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6u1rlatk\MarkupSafe\setup.py", line 132, in <module>
  try_building_extension()
File "C:\Users\suyash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6u1rlatk\MarkupSafe\setup.py", line 111, in try_building_extension
  run_setup(True)
File "C:\Users\suyash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6u1rlatk\MarkupSafe\setup.py", line 105, in run_setup
  features=features,
File "c:\python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
  dist.run_commands()
File "c:\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
  self.run_command(cmd)
File "c:\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 179, in run
  self.run_command('build')
File "c:\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
  self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "c:\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "c:\python36\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
  self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "c:\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
  self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "c:\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\suyash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6u1rlatk\MarkupSafe\setup.py", line 52, in run
  build_ext.run(self)
File "c:\python36\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 308, in run
  force=self.force)
File "c:\python36\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_compiler
  return klass(None, dry_run, force)
File "c:\python36\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 282, in __init__
  CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
File "c:\python36\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 157, in __init__
  self.dll_libraries = get_msvcr()
File "c:\python36\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 86, in get_msvcr
  raise ValueError("Unknown MS Compiler version %s " % msc_ver)
  ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1900
```

I have been searching the internet for a whole day and didn't find a solution.

**PS** - I am using python 3.6.2 - 64 bit.

Comment: try installing python and jupyter through anaconda

Comment: mention which command are using to install `jupyter notebook`

Comment: the last solution on the original question solved my problem